# Transition from PPC install to x86

Tags: server, intel, powerpc

I currently have a copy of ubuntu server 16.04 running on a powerPC system (Powermac G5) and I want to move it over to a newer Intel x86 system. Is there a way that I can keep my current install and just move the hard drive over, and somehow convert the OS to x86 (maybe by updating the kernel and packages). Or will I have to do a fresh install and migrate over?

Thanks